# "Those who hold ..." vs "Those whom hold ..."

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, whom, who

***Random English exercise for myself because I like words:***

> - Those who hold the plant will die.
> - Those whom hold the plant will die.

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

---

***Opinion:***

It is the first sentence because it sounds better... but who 'm I to judge? (Sorry for the pun :P)

I tried to structure the two sentences differently like the following, and see which sounded better:

> - He who holds the plant will die.
> - Him who holds the plant wil die.

From what I can tell, "he" refers to "who" and "him" refers to "whom". In my opinion, these *both* sound ok... but when I change "he" to "she" and "him" to "her", the second sentence sounds awful:

> - Her who holds the plant will die. (yikes!)

So I believe the first sentence most above is correct (i.e. the one with "who" as opposed to "whom").

---

***Made-up word:***

Enshadow:

*verb* 
 1. envelop in shadow (e.g. The moon will enshadow us once the eclipse begins.) 
 2. hide something discreetly (e.g. We thought he was honest, but the truth was enshadowed.)

Comment: (a) Don't ever use _whom_. You never need it. (2) _enshadow_ is a perfectly normal English verb; you may have made it up, but so did a lot of other people before you.

Comment: The person performing an action is always **he, she, who**. If the action is done to them it's **him, her, whom**. As @JohnLawler says, some people now consider using 'whom' to be old-fashioned and pedantic.

Comment: @JohnLawler really??? Ah well... I will make up another word then... thanks for telling me

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you! I see I kind of answered my own question, then, hahah, but at least you confirmed it :)